# If clauses in for loop acts weird

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

I have a function, which collects inputted answer and checked if collected answer is the same as it is the solution. Questions are asked randomly. Questions and solutions are in separate .txt file.

I have a file with some words and the program always fulfil its condition if the last word from the list is correctly answered, even though if other answers from other questions are correct.

Any suggestions?

```js
var besedeNemske = ["glava", "voda", "drevo"];
var besedePrevod = ["der Kopf", "das Wasser", "der Baum"];


window.onload = function() {
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
  var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');

  fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var textType = /text.*/;

    if (file.type.match(textType)) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e) {

        var lines = this.result.split('\n');
        for (var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {
          if (line % 2 != 0) {
            besedeNemske.push(lines[line]);
          } else {
            besedePrevod.push(lines[line]);
          }
        }

      }

      reader.readAsText(file);
    } else {
      fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!"
    }
  });
}



var random = 0;

function nastaviRandom() {
  random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
}

function noviGlagol() {

  nastaviRandom();

  document.getElementById("vprasanje").innerHTML = besedePrevod[random];

}

function preveriOdgovor() {
  var odgovorjeno = document.getElementById("mojOdgovor").value;
  if (besedeNemske.indexOf(odgovorjeno) == random) {
    document.getElementById("odgovor").innerHTML = "Pravilni odgovor";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("odgovor").innerHTML = "Napačen odgovor.   Pravilni odgovor je " + (besedeNemske[random]) + "";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page-wrapper">

    <h1>Nemščina glagoli</h1>
    <div>
      Select a text file:
      <input type="file" id="fileInput">
    </div>
    <pre id="fileDisplayArea"><pre>

        <button onclick="noviGlagol()">Novi glagol</button>

        <div id="vprasanje"></div>
        <div id="odgovor"></div>

        <input type="text" id="mojOdgovor">
        <button onclick="preveriOdgovor()">Pošlji</button>
</div>
<script>
</script>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: FYI, your loop can be replaced with `index = besedeNemske.indexOf(odgovorjeno)`

Comment: Does `random` get initialized/assigned a value anywhere? if so, where/how?

Comment: Please post your HTML

Comment: Which `if` is giving you a problem? `if (odgovorjeno == besedeNemske[i])` or `if (index == random)`?

Comment: Your loop can't tell the difference between the input not matching anything and matching the first element of the array. In both cases it will be `index = 0`. You need to use a different value for not found.

Comment: @Barmar I do know that, this is not hard to correct. But the problem is in the other words, because program know that are same, but not pass them through the first if-clause.

Comment: Have you checked what is the value of `random` for each case? Debug it to see why if does not get into the first `if` clause

Comment: @Alfabravo I have. I havee checked everything in the console.

Comment: You have a typo: `besedePrevodi` is the name of the array, but you use `besedePrevod[i]` in the function.

Comment: There's no element with `id="myAnswer"`, so `document.getElementById("myAnswer").value` fails.

Comment: @Barmar No it is not here the problem, when I was copying code from editor I've lost that 'i' and I translated it in English. In my source code it was and is correct.

Comment: Since the arrays are empty, there's nothing for the input to match. How is that code supposed to work?

Comment: @Barmar ...read the comment. Other part of a program fills elements in the arrays.

Comment: I understand that. But since your example doesn't run that part, it's not filled in, so we can't test your code. Provide a working example so we can see what it's doing wrong.

Comment: The code seems to work. I press the first button, it displays `das Wasser`. Then I enter `voda` into the input field and press the second button, it says `Pravilni odgovor`. If I enter something else, it says `Napačen odgovor.   Pravilni odgovor je voda`

Comment: @Barmar Fun fact: it works if you manually add elements to array, but not if program does that. It seems like the part of the program which fills array with elements from a file doesn't equate them to manually added one's. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'll bet there are characters in the file that you're not seeing, maybe spaces at the end of the lines. Try using `.push(lines[line].trim)`

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. Now it is working! But is weird, given the fact that the console have showed "sth" instead of "sth ".

Answer (score 0):

To submit the comments on the original question as an answer:

```
var index = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < besedeNemske.length; i++) {
  if (odgovorjeno == besedeNemske[i]) {
    index = i;
    break;
  }
}
```

`index` will be `0` for both of these cases:

1. if `odgovorjeno == besedeNemske[0]`
2. if `odgovorjeno` is not an element in the array `besedeNemske`

This is a really good use case for refactoring your code to use included language functionality or libraries, as it not only shortens your code, but is usually more correct (or at least their bugs are known/understood).

As Baramar pointed out, you can change your solution to:

```
function preveriOdgovor() {
  var odgovorjeno = document.getElementById("mojOdgovor").value;
  if (besedeNemske.indexOf(odgovorjeno) == random) {
    document.getElementById("odgovor").innerHTML = "Pravilni odgovor";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("odgovor").innerHTML = "Napačen odgovor.   Pravilni odgovor je " + (besedeNemske[random]) + "";
  }
}
```

Comment: I mentioned this issue in the comments, he said it's not the problem he's having.

Comment: Thank you. But it still doesn't work. Solution is for example 'voda' and I type in 'voda' and it say it isn't correct. But if I enter 'drevo' (it is the last element in array) when it asked me for it, it shows that it is correct. It seems like the program likes just the last element of the array.

Comment: @Barmar I posted whole program ;)

Comment: That doesn't help, since we don't have a file to load into the script. Create a minimal example that demonstrates the problem you're having. Leave out anything not related to the problem. So we don't need the file, we just need an array that contains strings.

Comment: @Barmar I filled the array with some words :)